# Can I access class variables using self?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I have a class `Foo` with a class variable `remote`. Can I access the class variable `remote` using `self.remote`?

```
class Foo:
   remote = False

   def __init__(self):
       self.remote = True 

   @classmethod
   def print_remote(cls):
       print(cls.remote) #prints False but why?
```

Comment: You have both a *class level* and an *instance level* of `remote` - what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to know if self.remote and cls.remote are same variables or different.

Comment: if only cls.remote is defined and not self.remote via the __init__ constructor then self.remote and cls.remote reference the same variable. Otherwise they are different as per your example provided

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Assigning `remote` to `self` in `__init__` means that `instance.remote` is found first when you access it through `self` (granted no descriptors are around). To get both options, access either from `self` or from `type(self)`, that is, either from the instance or the class:

```
def print_remote(self):
    print(type(self).remote) # class remote
    print(self.remote)       # instance remote
```

<sub>`type(self).remote` is essentially equivalent to `self.__class__.remote` but, in general, you should avoid grabbing dunder names (`__*__`) when there's a built in that does it for you (`type` in this case)</sub>

These live in different dictionaries and are different variables. `self.remote` lives in the instance dict while `class.remote` in the class dict.

```
>>> Foo().__dict__['remote']
True
>>> Foo.__dict__['remote']
False
```

When you access through `cls` with a `classmethod` (or `type(self)` in a normal method) you'll get the class one, when you access through `self` you get the instance one.

Comment: It's nice to be able to acess both `remote` variables, but I don't like the fact that two different things have the same name. With regards to the broadly used `m_` notation for instance members, I like to prefix my class variables with `c_`. This disambiguates calls such as `self.remote`, which either becomes `self.c_remote` or `self.m_remote`.

Comment: Great explanation Thanks.

Comment: Also note that `self.__class__.remote` is equivalent to `type(self).remote`.

Comment: @Rightleg right, I'll clarify that. Thanks! You're welcome, 2ank3th.

Answer (score 6):

```
In [1]: class Foo:
   ...:     x = 0
   ...:

In [2]: f = Foo()

In [4]: f.__dict__ # empty
Out[4]: {}

In [5]: Foo.__dict__ # have the variable x = 0
Out[5]:
mappingproxy({'__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'Foo' objects>,
              '__doc__': None,
              '__module__': '__main__',
              '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'Foo' objects>,
              'x': 0})
```

When you try access a variable in a object, Python will look first in the object, if it is not there then it looks in class dict.

```
In [6]: Foo.x = 10 # changing class variable

In [7]: f.__dict__ # still empty.
Out[7]: {}

In [8]: f.x # gives you Foo's x as object doesn't have that item.
Out[8]: 10

In [9]: f.x = 20 # this line creates a new variable in x. Now both class and object has their own variable x

In [10]: f.__dict__ # f has its own x.
Out[10]: {'x': 20}

In [11]: Foo.__dict__ # Foo has its own x.
Out[11]:
mappingproxy({'__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'Foo' objects>,
              ...
              'x': 10})
In [12]: f.x # always you will get the value from f.__dict__
Out[12]: 20
In [16]: f.x = 50 # changing the value of object's variable

In [17]: Foo.x # above statement didn't affect class's variable.
Out[17]: 10

In [13]: del f.x # delete object's x

In [14]: f.x # now f doesn't have x, you get the value from class Foo.
Out[14]: 10
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can access the class variable with self. But, in case you have an instance variable, you will be accessing the instance variable when you use self as it is shadowing the class variable.